# Error #1136 - El número de columnas no corresponde al número en la línea 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Cuando le doy continuar me dice:

> #1136 - El número de columnas no corresponde al número en la línea 1

No se que hacer, esta es mi consulta:

```sql
Insert into Vuelos (Personal,Clientes,Quejas) VALUES(
    'Carlos Dominguez','Camila Perez',2,
    'Monica Naranjo','Ricardo Sanchez',1,
    'Juan Rodriguez','Angelica Rosas',5,
    'Paulina Estrada','Oscar Hernandez',3,
    'Pedro Gonzalez','Emma Flores',6,
    'Lucas Mendez','Nidia Cruz',4);
```

Comment: El problema te dice calaramente que es lo que está sucediendo: El numero de columnas no corresponde con el número de líneas. Esto quiere decir que tu cuando pones `Insert into Vuelos (Personal,Clientes,Quejas)` le vas a pasar solo esas tres columnas, y dentro del `VALUES` donde le pasas los datos le estás pasando muchos más. Por lo que veo Tendrías que hacer 6 sentencias, y en cada una pasarle los datos justos. Es decir, en la primera le pasas los datos de "Carlos Dominguez", en la siguiente la de "Monica Naranjo"...

Answer (score 2):

Cuando colocas:

```
                                  col3--┐ 
                          col2--┐       |
                 col1--v        v       v
Insert into Vuelos (Personal,Clientes,Quejas)
```

Estas indicando a cuales columnas vas insertar, en tu caso son 3.

Luego en `VALUES` deben ir 3 y solo 3 columnas

```
VALUES('nombre','nombre',34)
```

Quedando de esta manera

```
Insert into Vuelos (Personal,Clientes,Quejas) VALUES('nombre','nombre',34)
```

Tu estas ingresando múltiples columnas en una fila, de ahí tu error. Cuando lo que tu quieres es ingresar múltiples filas, cuya sintaxis es:

```
Insert into Vuelos (Personal,Clientes,Quejas) 
VALUES
  ('Carlos Dominguez','Camila Perez',2), 
  ('Monica Naranjo','Ricardo Sanchez',1),
  ('Juan Rodriguez','Angelica Rosas',5),
  ('Paulina Estrada','Oscar Hernandez',3),
  ('Pedro Gonzalez','Emma Flores',6),
  ('Lucas Mendez','Nidia Cruz',4);
```